# What is our stance on questions asking about a program in beta version?

Tags: discussion, scope

What is our stance on questions asking about a program in beta version? Are they on-topic or off-topic?

Answer (score 3):

If the question would be on topic for the equivalent general release software I think it would be OK.

Fewer people will have access to beta versions so there will be fewer, poorer answers.

Comment: major software beta programs should probably have its own tag. This already happens for some but I don't know if it's consistently applied.